# How to change the directory of hazelcast.mancenter.home

Tags: tomcat, hazelcast

I am very new to Hazelcast. I deploy the mancenter in tomcat, and want to change the hazelcast.mancenter.home to another directory instead of the default one.

In the hazelcast documentation, saying to update the system properties. What is exactly the file and system properties I can update in linux environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can start your JVM with the flag `-Dhazelcast.mancenter.home=your_directory`